# StatusBarIOS Color Change on Page Load in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to change the colour of the StatusBarIOS on the page load. The documentation [StatusBarIOS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/statusbarios.html), the example shows how to change the accent of the Status Bar on the action of a Touch Highlight. I want this to happen automatically on page load.

Also is there a possibility of setting the StatusBarIOS colour to the whole application itself without applying it in every page?

Answer (score 1):

In your route js file (index.ios.js) just do this:

```
componentWillMount: function() {
  return StatusBarIOS.setStyle(1);
}
```

This will make the status bar white throughout your entire app. Take into consideration that if you are switching to another app from your app, for example to the Camera Roll app for picking a file to upload, you will probably need to set the color to white again as that app changes it to black.

If that doesn't work, try requiring a different file from your initial file and then do it there:

```
index.ios.js:

var App, AppRegistry, React;

React = require('react-native');

AppRegistry = React.AppRegistry;

App = require('./app/dist/App');

AppRegistry.registerComponent('yourapp', function() {
  return App;
});


app.js
componentWillMount: function() {
  return StatusBarIOS.setStyle(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this only handled the look for the first page only (That gets redirected from the index.ios.js). Other pages had the default (Black) theme. :/